# FFMPEG screen capture and game display

Tags: linux, windows, command-line, video, ffmpeg

I was looking on the internet for screen capturing software and I found two, namely **Camtasia** and **ADOBE CAPTIVATE (2017 RELEASE)**. Both are commercial products, but then I discovered that the free open source ffmpeg can do the same thing.

I searched on google and youtube for the commands and found the following:

List Devices

```
ffmpeg -list_devices true -f dshow -i dummy
```

Sample output:

```
ffmpeg version N-82143-gbf14393 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-nvenc --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-libebur128 --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      55. 35.100 / 55. 35.100
  libavcodec     57. 65.100 / 57. 65.100
  libavformat    57. 57.100 / 57. 57.100
  libavdevice    57.  2.100 / 57.  2.100
  libavfilter     6. 66.100 /  6. 66.100
  libswscale      4.  3.100 /  4.  3.100
  libswresample   2.  4.100 /  2.  4.100
  libpostproc    54.  2.100 / 54.  2.100
[dshow @ 00000000007466c0] DirectShow video devices (some may be both video and audio devices)
[dshow @ 00000000007466c0]  "Integrated Webcam"
[dshow @ 00000000007466c0]     Alternative name "@device_pnp_\\?\usb#vid_1bcf&pid_2b8a&mi_00#6&252f9170&0&0000#{65e8773d-8f56-11d0-a3b9-00a0c9223196}\global"
[dshow @ 00000000007466c0] DirectShow audio devices
[dshow @ 00000000007466c0]  "Stereo Mix (Realtek Audio)"
[dshow @ 00000000007466c0]     Alternative name "@device_cm_{33D9A762-90C8-11D0-BD43-00A0C911CE86}\wave_{ADF37977-4572-40C3-A4B8-E1674AD4D12D}"
[dshow @ 00000000007466c0]  "Microphone (Realtek Audio)"
[dshow @ 00000000007466c0]     Alternative name "@device_cm_{33D9A762-90C8-11D0-BD43-00A0C911CE86}\wave_{1E07BFD6-2D61-4A47-A11C-C0D5E170CB15}"
dummy: Immediate exit requested
```

Next, Campture screen:

```
ffmpeg -y -rtbufsize 200M -f gdigrab -thread_queue_size 1024 -probesize 10M -r 30 -draw_mouse 1 -i desktop -f dshow -channel_layout stereo -thread_queue_size 1024 -i audio="audio device" -c:v libx264 -r 30 -preset ultrafast -tune zerolatency -crf 25 -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a aac -strict -2 -ac 2 -b:a 128k "video output.mp4"
```

Substitute a valid audio name for `"audio device"` in `-i audio="audio device"`, from the previous command.

Now, this worked well for me, but when I tested the recording for a real game, it was slow. So my question is, how to improve the capture for game display?

p.s: I am working under windows 10 operating system.

Answer (score 2):

See: [Here](https://obsproject.com/).

Under Windows OBS is the best free recording tool.  It will do most games just fine but it's finicky for setting up a game.  Usually you have to launch the game, switch back to your desktop without quitting the game, and then in OBS point it at the game's screen (which exists when it's running in the background) and then you're good to go.

It's seems complicated at first but that is only because it can do almost everything.  Persist with it and you will certainly get the job done.

Comment: OBS is also available for Linux and MacOS so if you learn it on Windows you can take the skill to other platforms.